# Can I put back a partitioner to a PairRDD after transformations?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

It seems that the "partitioner" of a pairRDD is reset to None after most transformations (e.g. `values()` , or `toDF()` ). However my understanding is that the partitioning may not always be changed for these transformations.

Since cogroup and maybe other examples perform more efficiently when the partitioning is known to be co-partitioned, I'm wondering if there's a way to tell spark that the rdd's are still co-partitioned.

See the simple example below where I create two co-partitioned rdd's, then cast them to DFs and perform `cogroup` on the resulting rdds. A similar example could be done with values, and then adding the right pairs back on.

Although this example is simple, my real case is maybe I load two parquet dataframes with the same partitioning.

Is this possible and would it result in a performance benefit in this case?

```
data1 = [Row(a=1,b=2),Row(a=2,b=3)]
data2 = [Row(a=1,c=4),Row(a=2,c=5)]
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(data1)
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(data2)

rdd1 = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x.a,x)).partitionBy(2)
rdd2 = rdd2.map(lambda x: (x.a,x)).partitionBy(2)

print(rdd1.cogroup(rdd2).getNumPartitions()) #2 partitions

rdd3 = rdd1.toDF(["a","b"]).rdd
rdd4 = rdd2.toDF(["a","c"]).rdd

print(rdd3.cogroup(rdd4).getNumPartitions()) #4 partitions (2 empty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `scala` api most transformations include the

```
preservesPartitioning=true
```

option.  *Some* of the python RDD api's retain that capability: but for example the

```
groupBy
```

is a significant exception.  As far as `Dataframe` API's the partitioning scheme seems to be mostly outside of end user control - even on the `scala` end.

It is likely then that you would have to:

- restrict yourself to using rdds - i.e. refrain from the DataFrame/Dataset approach
- be choosy on which RDD transformations you choose: take a look at the ones that do allow either

  - retaining the parent's partitioning schem
  - using preservesPartitioning=true

Comment: This makes sense. Looking at the scala code for preservesPartitioning it seems like it simply preserves the Partitioner object. Is there no way I can manually reattach it after one or more transformations?

Comment: @retrocookie  A  partitioner is an integral part of each transformation and thus needs to be specified at that time to obtain non-default behavior.  Some of the spark methods do by default retain the parent partitioning but SQL/dataframes do not in many cases

Comment: I still feel there is some piece of explanation missing. If I turn a partitioned RDD (with no partitioner) back into a PairRDD and I know how the keys are distributed via partitions, it seems I should be able to (cheaply) tell spark it still has the same partitioner. Similarly, is there an inherent reason `toDF` and `values` can't have the same argument preservesPartitioning? After all for the case of `values`, I can achieve the same functionality with `map`.

Comment: @retrocookie  "Should" is true: but "can" is not necessarily the case. The point of my answer is that one has to (a) check the api's to see if they offer the `preservesPartitioning` parameter and (b) if not, then dig into the Spark source code to see what they do for the default case. For (b) there is a surprising variety of actual approaches.  For Spark SQL the author has told me they tend to avoid re-using parent partitioners because of the potential for misuse by novice users.  I would like to see a partitioning API for advanced users but for spark sql (/dataframes) it is not in place.